# trying to add some Js strings together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following form:

```
<form id="taskform">

                Habit: <input id="taskname" type="text">

                <textarea id="taskdesc" rows="4" cols="50" name="comment" form="usrform">Description Here...</textarea> 

                <div>
                    Good or Bad:
                    <input type="radio" id="star" name="priority" value="1" checked/><label for="star1" title="Not very important">Good</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="star" name="priority" value="2"/><label for="star2" title="Kinda important">Bad</label>
                </div>

                <br>Starting Date: <input id="deadlinedate" type="date">
                Times you want to do it: <input type="number" id="reminderdays" min="0"> 

                <span type="button" id="sBtn" value="Add Habit" onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn" >Add Habit</span>
                <input type="reset" value="Clear">

            </form>
```

I have a js function which takes the values of each field here and it should add them together:

```
var li = document.createElement("li");
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("taskname").value;
  var inputDescription = document.getElementById("taskdesc").value;
  var inputStar = document.getElementById("star").value;
  var inputDate = document.getElementById("deadlinedate").value;
  var inputReminderDays = document.getElementById("reminderdays").value;

  var t1 = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  var t2 = document.createTextNode(inputDescription);
  var t3 = document.createTextNode(inputStar);
  var t4 = document.createTextNode(inputDate);
  var t5 = document.createTextNode(inputReminderDays);
```

now I am trying to combine all of the strings `t1,t2,t3,t4` and `t5` together and then add to a list object.

it does add to a list if I use just for example `t1`, by doing this:

```
li.appendChild(t1);
```

if I use concat and try to add `t2, t3, t4` and `t5` to my `t1` and then use this

`li.appendChild(res);`

with `res` being the sum of all of the values my list is empty and nothing is added,

i am not sure how to do this, I dont know why concat or + doesnt work.

also I can not get the value for my date and radio for some reason.

Comment: Why not add the strings together *before* making a *single* text node?

Comment: it does not look like you are using jQuery yet you have the tag: [tag:jquery] do you want a raw JS answer or a jQuery answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is to combine the strings then nhy not try this:

```
var t1 = document.createTextNode(inputValue+' '+inputDescription+' '+inputStar+' '+inputDate+' '+inputReminderDays);
```

UPDATE:

```js
var output = document.getElementById('output');

function newElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("taskname").value;
  var inputDescription = document.getElementById("taskdesc").value;
  var inputStar1 = document.getElementById("star1");
  var inputStar2 = document.getElementById("star2");
  var inputDate = document.getElementById("deadlinedate").value;
  var inputReminderDays = document.getElementById("reminderdays").value;

  // Since you only have two radio buttons you can use a ternary to get the right value base on if oneis checked or not.
  var inputStar = inputStar1.checked ? inputStar1.value : inputStar2.value;

  var t1 = document.createTextNode(inputValue + ', ' + inputDescription + ', ' + inputStar + ', ' + inputDate + ', ' + inputReminderDays);
  li.appendChild(t1);
  output.appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<form id="taskform">
  Habit: <input id="taskname" type="text"><br/>
  <textarea id="taskdesc" rows="4" cols="50" name="comment" form="usrform" placeholder="Description Here..."></textarea>
  <div>
    Good or Bad:
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="priority" value="1" checked/><label for="star1" title="Not very important">Good</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="priority" value="2" /><label for="star2" title="Kinda important">Bad</label>
  </div>

  <br>Starting Date: <input id="deadlinedate" type="date"> Times you want to do it: <input type="number" id="reminderdays" min="0" value="1">

  <button type="button" id="sBtn" value="Add Habit" onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn">Add Habit</button>
  <input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
<hr/>
<ul id="output">
</ul>
```

Comment: yes I made it , it worked, however I can not get the value for startdate and  teh radio buttons.

Comment: You can't have two elements with the same `id` and both your checkboxes have `id="star"`. Instead you need to use different ids for each radio button and get the value based on which one has `el.checked === true` (`el` being the radio button)

Comment: can u write it dwon?

Comment: I added a better example